# Xaml served from the server?

Tags: c#, xaml

I've been asked to serve xaml up from the server and render it on a client. The client wants to have someone on staff be able to edit xaml pages and have them show up in a small business application on a tablet. There are about 5 users and there will not be more so I don't have to worry terribly about round trips. The app is using .net standard on the front end, net Core on the server. Is what they want even possible? I suggested putting in a browser and letting them edit the html and css but they want xaml. But they don't want a browser they want it to be xaml from the server with no browser.

Would I store and retrieve xaml from the back end or compile it into a blob and serve it back and what would I need to do on the client to have it render? Really hoping you smart folks can point me in the right direction or say what they are asking for is not possible with xaml.

Much appreciated.
Chuck

Comment: Have a look at [`FlowDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.flowdocument?view=windowsdesktop-6.0). Maybe that would work in your case, but not really sure.

Comment: Hey Chuck, you said, "The client wants to have someone on staff be able to edit xaml pages and have them show up in a small business application on a tablet."... I hear this and wonder if they just want access to a repo to make some small tweaks. Might be completely off here, but might be worth asking what they want to edit.